# Configurar parametro sZeroRecord do Datatable mas sem paginação

Tags: jquery, datatable

Estou utilizando a função `DataTable`:

```
"oLanguage": {
                "sZeroRecords": "Não há registros para mostrar"
            }
        });
```

Mas na minha tela aparece os botões de exportar, paginação sem eu ter configurado essas opções...
No caso eu gostaria só de utilizar `sZeroRecords` sem as outras opções, eu consigo fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Paging Description**
>
> DataTables can split the rows in tables into individual pages, which
> is an efficient method of showing a large number of records in a small
> space. The end user is provided with controls to request the display
> of different data as the navigate through the data. **This feature is
> enabled by default, but if you wish to disable it, you may do so with
> this parameter.**

Conforme a documentação, se você não setar nada, o padrao é true, ou seja, terá paginação(como descrito acima) e outras features também por padrao. Para desativar algumas features, veja um exemplo:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    paging: false,    // desativa paginação 
    ordering: false, //desativa ordenação no cabeçalho
    searching: false // desativa a pesquisa no topo
} );
```

Veja um exemplo na propria documentação **[aqui](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html)**

**Referencias:**

https://www.datatables.net/manual/options

https://datatables.net/reference/option